# saving the map function results in a list

Tags: perl

What will be the best way to print a list of strings which don't have trailing \n each in a different line ?

I tried the following and partialy succeeded:

```
@list = map { "${_}\n" } @list;
print @list;
@list = map { chomp } @list;
```

where the last line of code purpose is to restore the list to its original state.
the items in @list are printed each in a different line as I wanted, but @list contains only one element in it and its value is "1".

What I did wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) a list of values, just do

```
chomp(@list);
```

`chomp` does not return the modified value, but instead returns the total number of characters removed based off the [`$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

However, instead of modifying your original array in order to print each on a new line, just use a `for` loop

```
print "$_\n" for @list;
```

Comment: Or even `say for @list;`

Comment: @perlpilot TY for the attempted edit about number of characters.